# How to make button to appear at the center of the screen

Tags: flutter

I have been trying to make the button appear in the center but it displays the button at the bottom of the screen. So far I have used Align() function and Center() to make the button but it shrinks the size of the button. This is my current code.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return new Scaffold(
  appBar: new AppBar(
    title: Center(
      child: Text("Cooking Measurement Menu"),
    ),
  ),
  body: Container(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(
        16.0), //pushes the text field by that amount of pixel
    child: Column(
      // display all the component you have written above
      children: <Widget>[
        new Expanded(
          child: new Divider(),
        ),
        new Column(children: [
          new Row(children: [
            //5th row
            new Expanded(
                child: new OutlineButton(
              padding: new EdgeInsets.all(24.0),
              child: new Text(
                "Butter",
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontFamily: 'NotoSans',
                    fontSize: 20.0,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).push(_goToFirstPage());
              },
            ))
          ]),
        ])
      ],
    ),
  ),
);}
```

This code that I am trying to achieve is to have the button to have expended size and every time I want to have new button, I just added new Row under new Column. Hope it is clear. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Whats the purpose of your Divider widget that is wrap with Expanded(). That will cause to expand to its maximum height, causing your all other widget to be below

Comment: The Divider widget is based on an tutorial where I believe it at that time helps to expand the button size and start from the top of the screen. Many thanks, @Reign for your explanation in regards to my coding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

get rid of Expanded

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text("Cooking Measurement Menu"),
  ),
  body: Container(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(
        16.0),
    child:
        Column(children: [
          Divider(),
          Row(children: [
            //5th row
            Expanded(
                child: OutlineButton(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(24.0),
              child: Text(
                "Butter",
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontFamily: 'NotoSans',
                    fontSize: 20.0,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).push(_goToFirstPage());
              },
            ))
          ]),
        ])
  ),
);}
```

Comment: Thanks, Jim and the button is no longer at the bottom of the screen. Although, the button is at the top but I find a workaround where I put pad at the top of the screen,